# Rework custom collection to use whatever object

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

I have some code I always use to make collections of my object. This code and be used like 10 times in some of my project with the object replaced.

Is there any way I can create this as a function that can take whatever object? I've heard of `<T>` but I am unsure how to use it in this.

```
public class PageCollection : CollectionBase
    {
        public void Add(Page item)
        {
            InnerList.Add(item);
        }

        public void Remove(int index)
        {
            InnerList.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        public void Remove(Page item)
        {
            InnerList.Remove(item);
        }

        public Page this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return (Page)InnerList[index];
            }
            set
            {
                InnerList[index] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `List<T>` object to create strongly typed collection of your objects. In your example  use just

```
List<Page> listOfPages = new List<Page>()
```

Also check `System.Collections.Generic` namespace for strongly typed (generic) collections.

Comment: Is List<T> "better" than my custom collection? What are the benefits?

Comment: It's the same what your collection do, but the only difference: you don't need to create new type of collection for each type you are using, just specify your new type in `<>` and us strongly typed collection for free :) You will forget about creating strongly typed collection for your types.

Comment: Great. Guess I dont need to reinvent the wheel :P

Answer (score 0):

Best go to the source:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx